# Makefile overriding recipe error when string is used inside of echo

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile and I get an error when I use `all` target. I am not sure what is the root cause of the problem.

```
APSTOP= ../..
VERSION=2.12.8
SVERSION=2.12
SCALAC= /afs/package/scala/scala-${VERSION}/common/bin/scalac
APSLIB = ${APSTOP}/lib/aps-library-${SVERSION}.jar
COOLCOMPILERDIR= /afs/project/cool/scala
SCALAFLAGS= -cp .:${APSLIB}
SCALACFLAGS= ${SCALAFLAGS}
APS2SCALA = ${APSTOP}/bin/aps2scala
APS2SCALAFLAGS = -p ..:${APSTOP}/base -G
SCALASRC = cool-symbol.handcode.scala cool-semant-driver.scala cool-handcode.scala cool-noinherit-semant-driver.scala
SCALAGEN = cool-symbol.scala cool-tree.scala \
    cool-noinherit-semant.scala  cool-dynamic-semant.scala
SCALACOPY= basic.scala A2I.scala \
       CoolTokens.scala CoolScanner.scala CoolOptions.scala \
    CoolParser.scala 
SCALAHAND = CoolCompiler.scala
EXAMPLEDIR = ../examples

.PHONY: all clean src

src : ${SCALASRC}

all : ${SCALAGEN}
all : cool_symbol_implicit.class \
    cool_tree_implicit.class \
    cool_noinherit_semant_implicit.class \
    cool_dynamic_semant_implicit.class

%.scala : ../%.aps 
    ${APS2SCALA} ${APS2SCALAFLAGS} $*

cool-symbol.scala : ../cool-symbol.aps
    ${APS2SCALA} ${APS2SCALAFLAGS} --omit SYMBOL --omit gensym cool-symbol

%_implicit.class : %.scala
    ${SCALAC} ${SCALACFLAGS} $*.scala

cool_symbol_implicit.class : cool-symbol.scala cool-symbol.handcode.scala
    ${SCALAC} ${SCALACFLAGS} cool-symbol.scala cool-symbol.handcode.scala

cool_tree_implicit.class : cool-tree.scala cool_symbol_implicit.class
    ${SCALAC} ${SCALACFLAGS} cool-tree.scala

cool_noinherit_semant_implicit.class : cool-noinherit-semant.scala
    ${SCALAC} ${SCALACFLAGS} $<

cool_dynamic_semant_implicit.class : cool-dynamic-semant.scala
    ${SCALAC} ${SCALACFLAGS} $<

%.scala : RCS/%.scala,v
    co $<

.PHONY: %.run
%.run : %.class
    scala ${SCALAFLAGS} $*

.PHONY: %.compile
%.compile : %.scala
    scalac ${SCALACFLAGS} $*.scala

.PHONY: %.semant
%.semant : ${EXAMPLEDIR}/%.cool Semant.class
    scala ${SCALAFLAGS} CoolCompiler $<

.PHONY: %.debug
%.debug : ${EXAMPLEDIR}/%.cool Semant.class
    scala ${SCALAFLAGS} CoolCompiler -s $<

COOLCOMPILERSCALA = \
        cool-symbol.scala cool-symbol.handcode.scala cool-tree.scala \
        cool-handcode.scala ${SCALACOPY} \
        cool-dummy-semant-driver.scala ${SCALAHAND}

${SCALACOPY} :
    echo "import cool_implicit._" | cat - ${COOLCOMPILERDIR}/$@ > $@

CoolParser.scala :
    echo "import cool_implicit._" | cat - ${COOLCOMPILERDIR}/$@ > $@.tmp
    sed 's/result.set_inheritablep(/t_Tree.s_inheritablep(result,/' \
        < $@.tmp > $@

cool-parser-${SVERSION}.jar : ${COOLCOMPILERSCALA}
    @rm -f *.class
    ${SCALAC} -deprecation ${SCALACFLAGS} ${COOLCOMPILERSCALA}
    jar cvf $@ *.class

install: cool-parser-${SVERSION}.jar
    cp cool-parser-${SVERSION}.jar ../../lib/.

clean:
    rm -f *.class ${SCALAGEN} ${SCALACOPY} *.jar
```

Error:

```
Makefile:79: warning: overriding recipe for target 'CoolParser.scala'
Makefile:76: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'CoolParser.scala'
make: Nothing to be done for 'src'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not an error: if it was an error the build would have failed.  This build succeeded.  In make error messages contain `***`.  This is just a warning about a weird thing in your makefile.

To understand it you just have to look at the lines in your makefile that make is complaining about, and read the message it printed.

You have this variable set:

```
SCALACOPY= basic.scala A2I.scala \
   CoolTokens.scala CoolScanner.scala CoolOptions.scala \
   CoolParser.scala
```

So this variable contains `CoolParser.scala`.

Next at Makefile line 76, you have this:

```
${SCALACOPY} :
        echo "import cool_implicit._" | cat - ${COOLCOMPILERDIR}/$@ > $@
```

This defines rules telling make how to build all the targets in the variable `SCALACOPY`, including `CoolParser.scala`.

Then at Makefile line 79, you have this:

```
CoolParser.scala :
        echo "import cool_implicit._" | cat - ${COOLCOMPILERDIR}/$@ > $@.tmp
        sed 's/result.set_inheritablep(/t_Tree.s_inheritablep(result,/' \
            < $@.tmp > $@
```

This tells make *ANOTHER* rule also to build `CoolParser.scala`, which you already provided a rule for; make will drop the first rule and use the second rule, but it will also give you a warning message telling you about it because this is very unusual and not usually what you want to do:

```
Makefile:79: warning: overriding recipe for target 'CoolParser.scala'
Makefile:76: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'CoolParser.scala'
```

Comment: do you have a suggestion on how to fix this warning?

Comment: Yes: do not define two different recipes for the same target.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome descriptive explanation.